# Cannot get correct SoapAction namespace on ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I have looked at a number of sources both here on Stackoverflow and on the ServiceStack wiki and for the life of me I can't get my soap action to be the correct namespace.  I am using the latest nuget package (3.9.63).

My AppHost (in Assembly MyService.Service):

```
public class MyServiceAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public MyServiceAppHost()
        : base("My Services", typeof(MyServiceAppHost).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new ProtoBufFormat());
        Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());

        //This method scans the assembly for validators
        container.RegisterValidators(typeof(GetAccountValidator).Assembly);

        container.Register<IAccountInfoRepository>(
            c => new AccountInfoRepository(Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString))
                .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);


        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            DebugMode = true,
            WsdlServiceNamespace = "http://www.myCompany.com/types"
        });
    }
}
```

My Service (in Assembly MyService.Service):

```
public class ClientAccountService : Service
{
    private readonly IValidator<GetAccount> _validator;
    private readonly IAccountInfoRepository _repository;

    public ClientAccountService(IValidator<GetAccount> validator, IAccountInfoRepository repository)
    {
        _validator = validator;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public GetAccountResponse Any(GetAccount request)
    {
        request.Sanatize();

        var validationResult = _validator.Validate(request);

        if (validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            var account = _repository.GetAccountInfo(request.AccountNumber);

            if (null == account)
            {
                throw HttpError.NotFound(
                    Resources.ClientAccountService_AccountNotExistsErrorMsg.Fmt(request.AccountNumber));
            }
            return new GetAccountResponse { Account = account };
        }

        //The result will be serialized into a ValidationErrorException and thrown as such
        //The errors will be serialized in a clean, human-readable way 
        throw validationResult.ToException();
    }
}
```

My AssemblyInfo.cs contains (in Assembly MyService.Service):

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://www.myCompany.com/types", ClrNamespace = "MyService.Service")]
```

My Operations 
(in Assembly:MyService.ServiceModel Namespace:MyService.ServiceModel.Operations ):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.myCompany.com/types") , ProtoContract]
[Route("/Account/{AccountNumber}"]
public class GetAccount : IReturn<GetAccountResponse>
{
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(1)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; } 
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.myCompany.com/types"), ProtoContract]
public class GetAccountResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
    public GetAccountResponse()
    {
        ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus();
    }

    [DataMember, ProtoMember(1)]
    public AccountInfo Account { get; set; }

    // Automatic Exception Handling
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(2)]
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

(in Assembly:MyService.ServiceModel Namespace:MyService.ServiceModel.Types ):

```
[DataContract, ProtoContract]
public class AccountInfo
{
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(1)] public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(2)] public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(3)] public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(4)] public string RrNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(5)] public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(6)] public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(7)] public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(8)] public string AddressLine4 { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(9)] public string AddressLine5 { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(10)] public string AddressLine6 { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(11)] public string AddressLine7 { get; set; }
    [DataMember, ProtoMember(12)] public string AddressLine8 { get; set; } 
}
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs contains (in Assembly:MyService.ServiceModel)

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://www.myCompany.com/types", ClrNamespace = "MyService.ServiceModel.Operations")]
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://www.myCompany.com/types", ClrNamespace = "MyService.ServiceModel.Types")]
```

Technically, according to the documentation, I shouldn't need the "Namespace" definitions in the Operations Datacontract since I have the ContractNamespace defined, but since I can't get the soap definition right I am trying anything at this point.

My wsdl looks like:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:svc="http://www.myCompany.com/types" xmlns:tns="http://www.myCompany.com/types" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" name="Soap12" targetNamespace="http://www.myCompany.com/types">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
            <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
            <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
            <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
            <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
            <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
            <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="char">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="duration">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
                    <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
                    <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="guid">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.myCompany.com/types" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.myCompany.com/types">
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types"/>
            <xs:complexType name="GetAccount">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AccountNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="GetAccount" nillable="true" type="tns:GetAccount"/>
            <xs:complexType name="GetAccountResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Account" nillable="true" type="tns:AccountInfo"/>
                    <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" minOccurs="0" name="ResponseStatus" nillable="true" type="q1:ResponseStatus"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="GetAccountResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:GetAccountResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="AccountInfo">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AccountNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressLine1" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressLine2" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressLine3" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressLine4" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressLine5" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressLine6" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressLine7" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AddressLine8" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FirstName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LastName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RrNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="AccountInfo" nillable="true" type="tns:AccountInfo"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types">
            <xs:complexType name="ResponseStatus">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Message" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="StackTrace" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Errors" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfResponseError"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ResponseStatus" nillable="true" type="tns:ResponseStatus"/>
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfResponseError">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ResponseError" nillable="true" type="tns:ResponseError"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ArrayOfResponseError" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfResponseError"/>
            <xs:complexType name="ResponseError">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:appinfo>
                                <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                            </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FieldName" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:appinfo>
                                <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                            </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Message" nillable="true" type="xs:string">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:appinfo>
                                <DefaultValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" EmitDefaultValue="false"/>
                            </xs:appinfo>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ResponseError" nillable="true" type="tns:ResponseError"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetAccountIn">
        <wsdl:part name="par" element="tns:GetAccount"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetAccountOut">
        <wsdl:part name="par" element="tns:GetAccountResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ISyncReply">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetAccount">
            <wsdl:input message="svc:GetAccountIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="svc:GetAccountOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" type="svc:ISyncReply">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetAccount">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types/GetAccount" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SyncReply">
        <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply" binding="svc:WSHttpBinding_ISyncReply">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:55665/soap12"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

As you can see, the soapaction seems to be in the wrong namespace:
soapAction="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types/GetAccount"

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set `Config.WsdlSoapActionNamespace`, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{
    DebugMode = true,
    WsdlServiceNamespace = "http://www.myCompany.com/types",
    WsdlSoapActionNamespace = "http://www.myCompany.com/types",
});
```

I'll merge these 2 properties so you wont have to do this in v4.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Did I miss that in the docs or is the mismatch not an issue normally?

Comment: It's always been like that for granularity, but in reality in this case: less confusion > fine-grain control of WSDLs.

Comment: I'm not sure if this kind of thinking goes against ServiceStack coding philosophy, but maybe a solution like follows would offer both:  a third property called WsdlNamespace, that when set sets the other two properties automatically, otherwise you could set each one individually (which would clear the WsdlNamespace property) to offer that flexibility (unless that never makes sense, as you can tell I'm not very knowledgeable on soap/namespaces).

Comment: SS philosophy is to reduce complexity and required cognitive overhead, part of which means providing an opinionated 'pit of success' fx where we'd only surface only meaningful/relevant configuration to the end-user. In this case less properties is better than exposing more and forcing users to learn about the differences and behavior of each.